# How to change audio on click or embed in fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio, fancybox

I'm trying to include audio in a fancybox such that when you click an image and it pops-out audio will play as well. However, I don't want to download an external audio player but rather use the one that is currently included on the web page. Basically I simply want to change the audio that is currently playing by loading another MP3.

Here is the code for the audio player that is on the web page:

```
<div id="audioPlayerContainer" title="Audio Player">

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../flash/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="140" height="20">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="movie" value="../flash/player_mp3_maxi.swf">
<param name="FlashVars" value="configxml=../flash/config.xml&amp;mp3=../audio/intro/intro_08_background_07.mp3">
<p>Flash Audio Player</p>
</object>

</div>
```

How would I be able to change the audio that is played once the following link is clicked?

```
     <li style="float:left"><a href="../images/intro_characters_Raj.png" title="Raj Sharma" width="500"><img alt="Raj Sharma" src="../images/intro_characters_Raj.png" /></a></li>
```

This link has a fancybox script attached to it which is shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#clientPic li a").fancybox();
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example based on your code snippet, kindly check if this will suit your needs.

**HTML**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />

<ul style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="Now Playing: Sample 1">Launch Sample 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" title="Now Playing: Sample 2">Launch Sample 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="#inline3" title="Now Playing: Sample 3">Launch Sample 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="inline1" style="width: auto; display: none;" >
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width=200 height=20>
    <param name="movie" value="http://96.245.187.180:80/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=broadwavelow.mp3?src=fBroadWave Recording Example" />
    <param name="quality" value="best" />
    <embed src="http://96.245.187.180:80/player_mp3_maxi.swf" flashvars="mp3=broadwavelow.mp3?src=fBroadWave Recording Example" width=200 height=20 quality=best type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    <p>Sample 1</p>
    </object>
</div>

<div id="inline2" style="width: auto; display: none;" >
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width=200 height=20>
    <param name="movie" value="http://96.245.187.180:80/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=broadwavelow.mp3?src=fBroadWave Recording Example" />
    <param name="quality" value="best" />
    <embed src="http://96.245.187.180:80/player_mp3_maxi.swf" flashvars="mp3=broadwavelow.mp3?src=fBroadWave Recording Example" width=200 height=20 quality=best type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
    <p>Sample 2</p>
</div>

<div id="inline3" style="width: auto; display: none;" >
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width=200 height=20>
    <param name="movie" value="http://96.245.187.180:80/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=broadwavelow.mp3?src=fBroadWave Recording Example" />
    <param name="quality" value="best" />
    <embed src="http://96.245.187.180:80/player_mp3_maxi.swf" flashvars="mp3=broadwavelow.mp3?src=fBroadWave Recording Example" width=200 height=20 quality=best type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    <p>Sample 3</p>
    </object>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

So basically there are 3 hidden divs, each with the corresponding players and .mp3. The corresponding div is loaded inside fancybox (See values in href).​

Check also this link to see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hNLdk/ Good luck.